# ES6: how to multiple import as an alias (import { one, two } as parent)

Tags: ecmascript-6, turfjs

I'm using turf library, and import things like this:

```js
import * as turf from "@turf/turf";

const myCoords = turf.getCoords(...);
const myNearestPoint = turf.nearestPoint(...);
```

But I only use few functions and would like to reduce my bundle size, **WITHOUT** loosing the `turf` alias.

So I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```js
import { getCoords, nearesPoint } as turf from "@turf/turf"; // doesn't work

const myCoords = turf.getCoords(...);
const myNearestPoint = turf.nearestPoint(...);
```

Any ideas to make multiple imports within an alias?

Thanks!

Comment: If your going to use tree shaking you have to use `getCoords` as a function.
You could after your import line say `const turf = { getCoords, nearestPoint }` to combine them back into an object, but I would say this is bad practice and just adds needless complexity.

Comment: You can use this option: `import { getCoords as turf_getCoords, nearesPoint as turf_nearesPoint} from "@turf/turf"` and then use it like `const myCoords = turf_getCoords(...);`

Answer (score 5):

You can combine them back into an object after you import them.

```
import { getCoords, nearesPoint } from "@turf/turf";
const turf = { getCoords, nearesPoint };
```